# Cartthrob: Does the Purchased Items channel call ‘entry_submission_end’ EE hook?

Tags: cartthrob

When an order is complete, and a new entry has been created within the ‘Purchased Items’ channel, does the `entry_submission_end` EE hook fire? I need to process some data as orders are completed with the data held within this channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `cartthrob_on_authorize` hook. From there you can find the entry ID's of the saved purchased items entries:

```
$entry_ids = $this->EE->cartthrob->cart->order('purchased_items');

foreach ($entry_ids as $entry_id)
{
    //do some more processing here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CartThrob doesn't use the Channel Entries API, so the entry_submission_end hook is never triggered. You will need to use one of the hooks they provide instead.